# Where is Myrkul's return detailed?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

Due to the Second Sundering, old Gods have returned in the Forgotten Realms. I know that my favourite god from AD&D, Myrkul, has become alive once more.

Now I'm looking for any available official informations about him and his comeback. Basic informations can be found in the main D&D 5ed manuals, but does he appears in any other books, whether RPG manuals or novels?

Comment: Ah, I always welcome FR lore. But perhaps it's too similar to this question: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49373/did-kelemvor-lose-the-death-domain-to-myrkul

Comment: Well, I wanted detailed information about Myrkuls comeback, as well as any source where he appears. What is more, the question was answered in 2014, and is suggesting, that Myrkul is still dead, while now back in 2016 we know that he returned :)

Comment: Also related: [Are the Old Deities really coming back for D&D 5e's Forgotten Realms?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45544/are-the-old-deities-really-coming-back-for-dd-5es-forgotten-realms)

Answer (score 5):

As best I can determine, the return of Myrkul post Sundering is not actually detailed anywhere yet.

There are references to Myrkul in one sundering novel, but they aren't actually helpful to what you're looking for.

> In the Sundering novel "The Sentinel" by Troy Denning, there is a character who CLAIMS to be the Chosen of Myrkul through most of the book, but near the end is revealed to be the Chosen of Cyric, the masquerade part of an elaborate plan to let Cyric usurp Myrkul's old portfolio.

Answer (score 2):

Like for most other gods that came back with the Sundering that we find about in the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide (Leira, the drow pantheon, the dwarven and duergar pantheon, etc...) the answer is "mortals don't know, or mortals thought that they had died, when in truth they survived and hid until they recovered, or Ao did it".

The answer is intentionally vague, to leave DMs free to come up with their own reasons why the resurrected gods are back.